# nutch urls not fetched

Tags: java, regex, filter, web-crawler, nutch

Trying to crawl some urls from a local website from this domain:

```
https://foo.foofoo.com
```

But, I am not able to make it for specific ones like these in below. Because nutch skips them even it generates them in order to be fetched. But it does not make it:

```
https://foo.foofoo.com/foo/foo/foo/foo-a-foo-foofoo-foo-foo-foofoo-foo-foofoo
https://foo.foofoo.com/foo/00550000006yDdKAAU/foofoo/foo-foo-foo-foofoo-foo-foo
https://foo.foofoo.com/foo/foo/foo/foofoo-foo-foofoo-foo-foo/foofoo-a-foo-foofoo-foofoo?foo_id=foo-fi-and-foo-fafoo-fa
```

Only some urls (not all! only few!) like these get fetched:

```
https://foo.foofoo.com/en/foofoo
```

Here is my regex-urlfilter file, by which I only fetch english web pages:

```
-^(file|ftp|mailto):
-^https?://foo.foofoo.com/(de|ja|fr|es-MX|pt-BR)
+^https?://foo.foofoo.com
```

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: How depth do you use?

Comment: try this 
`-^(?:https?:\/\/)?foo\.foofoo\.com\/(?:de|ja|fr|es-MX|pt-BR)


+^(?:https?:\/\/)?foo\.foofoo\.com(?:\/.*|.*)`

Comment: Still the same. But I think your writing is better than mine. As depth, it is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing some useless plugins for my use case, everything went back alright. These plugins are **nutch-extensionpoints**, **parse-text** and **query(basic|site|url)**.

Comment: cool. For me i have this and its work maybe you do not need to delete as much
`protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|metadata|more|tika)|query-(basic|site|url)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|indexer-solr|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)`

Comment: I see. Thank you @Quent ! :)